# Laravel Eager Loading: Skip if relation exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

A **user** may have many **votes** and many **occasions**. An **occasion** can contain some of these **votes**.

*Peter has created three votes. He also has created one occasion with two votes. Peter has five votes at all.*

---

I want to fetch all votes, that are **not** part of an occasion for performance reasons.

This will load all votes:

```
$oUser->load( 'votes' );
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
$aLoad = array( 'votes' => function($query) {
   $query->whereNotIn('id', json_decode(json_encode(DB::raw('select id from occasions_votes')), true));
});
```

**My Problems**

1. It doesn't work. This still fetches all votes, even if the id exists in  the occasion_votes table.
2. This does not look like it would save performance.

**How would you solve it?**

Should I do multiple queries (fetch all vote ids > remove all vote ids that exists in occasions_votes > fetch votes of remaining ids) or is there a straight forard way to go? (Laravel 4.2)

Comment: My question is why would `$oUser->load( 'votes' );` load all votes?  It should load only the user's votes, not the user's occasion's votes as well.  It sounds like a schema change is in order and votes should be polymorphic to users and occasions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
App\User::with('votes')->whereHas('votes',function($query){
   $query->whereNotIn('id',DB::table('occasions_votes')->get()->lists('id')->all());
})
```

hope it helps.

Comment: `->lists('id')` was the way to go, didn't knew this method. But don't use `->all()` on `->lists()`, since `->lists()` returns an array, not an object.